# What changes do I make to this function to optimize the execution time?

Tags: c, performance, optimization

```
unsigned int lookup_bloom(unsigned char (*id)[HEXXID], unsigned int len,
        void *bf)
{
    int i;
    struct bloom_structure *filter = (struct bloom_structure *) bf;
    unsigned int *nexthop = NULL;
    // The returned values of counting_bloom_check() are 0 if found else 1
    unsigned char matchvec[WDIST] = {1};
    unsigned char tmp1[HEXXID + 1] = {0};
    unsigned char tmp2[HEXXID] = {0};

    memcpy(tmp1, id, HEXXID);
    memcpy(tmp2, tmp2, HEXXID);
    // Although the paper suggests to perform parallel membership queries
    for (i = len; i >= MINLENGTH; i--) {
        tmp1[i / BYTE] = tmp1[i / BYTE] >> (BYTE - i % BYTE) <<
                            (BYTE - i % BYTE);
        if (!filter->flag[i - MINLENGTH])
            continue;
        matchvec[i - MINLENGTH] =
        counting_bloom_check(filter->bloom[i - MINLENGTH], tmp1,
                                HEXXID);
    }
    // Parse the matchvec from longest to shortest to perform table search
    for (i = len; i >= MINLENGTH; i--) {
        tmp2[i / BYTE] = tmp2[i / BYTE] >> (BYTE - i % BYTE) <<
                            (BYTE - i % BYTE);
        if (matchvec[i - MINLENGTH] || !filter->flag[i - MINLENGTH])
            continue;
        nexthop = hashit_lookup(filter->hashtable[i - MINLENGTH],
                    tmp2);
        if (nexthop)
            return *nexthop;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here are some definitions used in the code:

```
#define WDIST 140
#define MINLENGTH 20

struct bloom_structure {
    bool flag[WDIST];
    unsigned int length[WDIST];
    int low[WDIST];
    int high[WDIST];
    counting_bloom_t *bloom[WDIST];
    hash_t hashtable[WDIST];
};
```

I am measuring the time of execution of this function.
Could anybody help me in optimizing this routine?

It would be great if someone could suggest any changes to write the loops in order to reduce the execution time.

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Profiling. And measure each piece of the code to see where the bottlenecks are (which basically is what profiling does).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how critical this function is you could try to minimize the number of divisions ( / and % ) performed as they are the most costly operations for the CPU.

You could possibly merge your two loops as they use the same range. This way you could use the same index calculations (those that imply divisions) in a variable.

If you really want to push this, you could precalculate all the indexes that imply division computation so that the values are accessed from an array or any container deemed fit.